# Linode Reboot - /dev/xvda has gone 220 days without being checked, check forced

Tags: linode

When rebooting a Linode server, and logging into the lish I am seeing:

```
/dev/xvda has gone 220 days without being checked, check forced.
```

When trying to reboot the server. I had run a routine command for the web server and received a seg fault, then upon rebooting experienced this.

What's odd is when I shut the server down it will work for a few minutes during reboot... then when turned back on continues to hang.

Answer (score 2):

```
/dev/xvda has gone 220 days without being checked, check forced.
```

This message is quite normal. You can change it with `tune2fs`:

- `-c` max-mount-counts
- `-i`  interval-between-checks

> I had run a routine command for the web server and received a segfault

What command did you run? Could you please show us the output? Did you try to debug with `gdb`?